# Fibonacci number using dp in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I have written two functions for Fibonacci numbers, one using recursion and the second using memorization(dynamic programming). Since the 2nd is using dp so it should run faster than the first one but the fact is the 2nd one takes more time than the 1st one.

Please correct me, if I have done some mistakes while writing functions.

Thanks in advance :)

Function 1:

```
long fibb(int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    return fibb(n - 1) + fibb(n - 2);
}
```

Function 2:

```
// long fib(int n, unordered_map<int, long> mp) (wrong)
long fib(int n, unordered_map<int, long> &mp) // correct
{
    if (mp.find(n) != mp.end())
        return mp[n];
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    mp[n] = fib(n - 1, mp) + fib(n - 2, mp);
    return mp[n];
}
```

Edit:- I attached the above code, earlier only images were there.
Solution:- I got the answer as I was missing the ampersand(&) from the arguments.

Function 1:

[image]

Function 2:

[image]

Comment: Code as text, not images please.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. It is text and should be included as such

Comment: And you are passing the `unordered_map` by value, meaning it has to be copied on each call to `fib` (and will also cause the memoization to not work as intended)

Comment: For this kind of small programs benchmarking take a look at https://www.quick-bench.com/

Comment: Instead of recursion, this would be simpler and faster with a loop and two variables storing the previous values. And safe from Stack Overflow risk.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for not posting the code earlier, However, I have attached the code now. I appreciate all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

`long fib(int n, unordered_map<int, long>& mp)` will be faster. Notice the `&` which passes the map by reference. This avoids a costly copy, and most importantly, avoids the modifications to the map from being lost.

Comment: It's not just faster, it will not perform any memorization at all otherwise. You are making it sound like the code is sub-optimal when it is straight-up non-functional.

Comment: Why pass it along at all, make it static in the function.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That would not be thread-safe though. For something that should behave like a side-effect-free function (caching aside), that's really misleading. It would need to at least be `thread_local`, but an external cache can also make sense. It depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: or protected by a mutex. Not sure an external cache would ever make sense. Having multiple caches in a thread just reduces the hit ratio. Thread local caches might make sense if there is a lot of contention but that's as far as I can see multiple caches being useful.

Comment: OP is confused about pass by reference versus by value. Not sure throwing the complexity of `static`, `thread_local` and `mutex` is the right move :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `std::unordered_map` by value. This means your code will always skip the `if` statements and go straight to fetching the Fibonacci number using the recursive function. You are still using the function that you thought you had avoided (at least when trying to fetch the same number twice from the `unordered_map`) which has its own cost plus the cost of setting up the stack frame of the function and copying the map each time. The second function is indeed slower.

Pass the unordered_map as a reference to avoid copying and most importantly, save the changes or the new values to the map.

```
long fib(int n, unordered_map<int, long> &mp)
```

Comment: Yeah, I forget the ampersand.